# Mootools store method: Where is the data stored?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I understand the idea of store some data with an element, but as a Javascript learner, I am curious where actually is the data stored by using this method.

The mootools help page is very simple and not helpful to me.

Can anyone tell me where I can find more comprehensive mootools help please?

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian, the MooTools community gives support here on Stackoverflow also. IMHO you suggestion is not appropriate.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian he's asking how it works / how it's implemented, not how to use it. it's fine suggesting dojo or jquery but then at least explain how it's written, why and what it solves. also, element storage was initially a MooTools idea before others adopted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way that storage actually works is simple.

in a closure where the method is defined, you have a private `{object}` used as a **dictionary** per element. Any methods from that closure can access the storage object but it's not puncture-able from the outside directly.

in working code:

```
(function(){
    // private shared object
    var Storage = {};

    /**
     * @param {string} key
     * @param {*} value
     * @return {HTMLElement}
     */
    Element.implement('write', function(key, value){
        // Slick can get a unique id for every element. this is key in storage
        var uid = Slick.uidOf(this),
            s = Storage[uid] || (Storage[uid] = {});
        return (s[key] = value), this;
    }); 

    /**
     * @param {string} key
     * @param {*=} initial value, optional
     * @return {*}
     */
    Element.implement('read', function(key, initial){
        var uid = Slick.uidOf(this),
            s = Storage[uid] || (Storage[uid] = {}),
            undef = 'undefined';
        typeof initial !== undef && typeof s[key] === undef && (s[key] = initial);
        return s[key];
    });

}());


var foo = document.id('foo');

foo.write('hello', 'there'); // save
console.log(foo.read('hello')); // read

console.log(foo.read('foo', 'bar')); // via initial value api, bar.
```

This is pretty much the full read/write api - only thing that is missing is the `.eliminate` functionality -- keep in mind it's slightly more defensive than the actual code, which was written with perf in mind so it does not typecheck so much.

http://jsfiddle.net/aj0pccew/2/

more here:

- http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:retrieve
- https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.js#L1003-L1019

as to why it's that way rather than on the element as an attribute, it's faster: only needs 1 attribute on the element itself (the `uid`), does not need DOM access to read/write stuff, avoids leaks via elements and circular references. It can also create leaks through removal of elements that previously had data in storage w/o the `destroy` API.

Comment: Thank you very much! That answered my question exactly. Though I still need some time to digest it.

Comment: A quick question(I hope it is appropriate to ask here): 
Is there any more explicit way to check what data(s) are stored with a particular element? That is, other than using .retrieve, besides, it seems to me using .retrieve requires you to know the keys before hand.

Comment: well. it's the nature of closures - you cannot puncture them to 'see' what's in it. but you can override the methods and start recording them. read http://fragged.org/hacking-mootools-elements-and-storage-uids_1649.html to see how you can puncture other els data - and you can overload the methods on the prototype and keep a record to find exactly what gets stored: http://jsfiddle.net/aevLcd1p/ - but this is kind of expensive and `destroy` won't clean redundant keys. storage is used by a lot of things internally (Fx etc).